# SQL to LINQ Statement including Group By and Order By

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an SQL query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Table1.Description, 
    Table2.AccountId, 
    COUNT(Table2.AccountId) AS Charges 
FROM Table2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.AccountId = Table1.Id 
WHERE Table2.DateTime > '3/1/2014' 
    AND Table2.DateTime < '4/1/2014' 
GROUP BY Table2.AccountId, Table1.Description 
ORDER BY Charges DESC
```

I am trying to convert this to a LINQ query in the ASPX.CS code behind to populate a table and to use the data in a chart.

What I have so far is below:

```
var resultList = configDB.Table2
    .Where(x => x.DateTime > begDate && x.DateTime < endDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.AccountID)
    .Select(g => new { Account = g.Key, Charges = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Charges)
    .ToList();
```

This is only the Table 2 portion.  I'm trying to join Table 1 as well and still get the count of Charges which from toying around with the code I was unable to get.  I've found several posts and solutions to do each one individually but not an answer where they are grouping by and joining while getting a count of a column.  Can anyone direct me to a resource that will help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried it with Query syntax ?

Comment: When I see `SELECT DISTINCT´ I immediately know that something is not right. The distinct is redundant here.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Just join Table1 before the Where. Wouldn't that work? That gives you pairs of (Table1, Table2) with Table1 possibly null. The rest of the query can work with those pairs.

Comment: @Justin it can be correct but experience shows that it is almost never the right thing to do. Experience derived from Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this (might need some tweaking)

```
var resultList = Table2
            .Where(x => x.DateTime > begDate && x.DateTime < endDate)
            .Join(Table1, t2 => t2.AccountId, t1 => t1.Id,
                (t2, t1) => new { t2.AccountId, t1.Description })
            .GroupBy(x => x.AccountId)
            .Select(g => new { Group = g, Charges = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Charges)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Select(x => new { x.Description, x.AccountId, g.Charges }))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I think that will do an inner join and not a left join.

Comment: If I do select instead of SelectMany it gives me a list of Counts which are the correct charge counts, and then if you expand that it's an entry of the name, accountId and charges for each of those.  So for example the top entry 20,000 entries, so it says a count of 20000, and when I expand that it's 20,000 entries of Description, Account, Charges.  With SelectMany it looks correct but looks like it needs a SELECT DISTINCT as there are several entries for each Description with the same information.

Comment: Okay, so doing Select instead of SelectMany and tacking a FirstOrDefault() at the end of that line gave me the result I was looking for.  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: I misunderstood a part of the question, so my solution was incorrect. I was looking into it, but you solved it yourself. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var resultList = configDB.Table2
                        .Where(x => x.DateTime > begDate && x.DateTime < endDate)
                        .GroupJoin(configDB.Table1,
                                    t2 => t2.AccountId,
                                    t1 => t1.Id,
                                    (t2, joined) => new
                                    {
                                        Description = joined.Select(t => t.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        AccountID = t2.AccountId,
                                    })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.AccountID)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            Account = g.Key, 
                            Charges = g.Count(), 
                            Description = g.Select(d=>d.Description).FirstOrDefault()
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Charges)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I believe this is close to what I'm trying to accomplish.  It appears the result set I get is a lot of repeating entries with a charges value of 1.  What I did in the original query is a count of the AccountId entries in Table2.  Although if I try t2.Count() instead of Joined.Count(), it doesn't work.  Why is it not able to do a count on t2, or is there another way to do that?

Comment: 'joined' is right side of left join statement. It's set of entries where Id=AccountId. I've just updated my answer, please try a new version.

Comment: After running the edited code I'm getting the following error: "DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument.\r\nParameter name: argument", am researching to see what is causing this.